# Is this do-able without an $x$ in the equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

I need help

Let's say you get a curve: $y=\frac{x-2}{2x+1}$

And the points are $(-1,3)$

You need to find the equation of the tangent

I differentiated it and it's derivative is $\frac{1}{2}$

Problem is, I can no longer sub in $x$ because there is no more $x$ in the derivative!

Did I do something wrong or is there another step to proceed further?

Comment: How did you get 1/2?

Comment: Differentiation

Comment: I differentiated it and got 1/2

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{2}$ the derivative of the function, or the derivative of the function at the point $x = -1$?

Comment: It is the derivative of the curve

Comment: So it should be at the function

Comment: What I'm asking is, did you substitute $x = -1$ into the derivative function yet, or did you find that the derivative is constantly $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: No, I did not do so

Comment: The derivative function is 1/2 which is the problem

Comment: I cannot sub $x$

Comment: OK, then you have not differentiated correctly. It is possible to have a constant derivative (in particular, if the curve is a straight line), in which case the derivative is that constant at $x = -1$ (as well as everywhere else).

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of this function is $$y'(x)=\frac{1}{2 x+1}-\frac{2 (x-2)}{(2 x+1)^2}=\frac{5}{(2 x+1)^2}$$ which can be found by using the product rule $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$$ using $f(x)=x-2$ and $g(x)=\left(2x+1\right)^{-1}$.
Plugging in $x=-1$ gives $y'(-1)=5$. This is the slope of your tangent. You can find the equation of your tangent using $y=mx+b$ with $m=5$ and $b$ can be found by using your given point $(x=-1,y=3)$ together with this equation.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: I'm still curious what you did to get $y'(x)=1/2$. I think you don't understand how to take a derivative and you will get into trouble later in your studies if you don't learn how to do this clearly. Cheers!

Comment: I used another differentiation method

Comment: And thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just so you know, except for linear and constant functions, your derivative should always be a function, not a number

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for the tip!

Comment: Since you're curious: I just converted $x$ into $1$ and threw away the two, then I turned $2x$ into 2 and threw away the one

Comment: That would work for each one separately, but if they are divided by each other, or multiplied by each other - you must use more sophisticated techniques

Comment: Is it ok if we move to chat so you can give me step by step? Just looking at the formula confuses me

Comment: Never mind, it sounds weird

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the time to go through this with you now, but have you ever worked on Khan Academy? It's a great way to learn, refresh and strengthen your math! https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab

Comment: Ok then thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actuelly your derivative is given by $$y'=\frac{2x+1-(x-2)2}{(2x+1)^2}=\frac{5}{(2x+1)^2}$$ so $$y'(-1)=5$$ and so do will get
$$y=5x+n$$ to compute $n$ plug in this equation $x=-1,y=3$

Comment: Thank you for that!